# Building Smartdiagram (Process Sequence Diagram)

Tags: tikz-pgf, smartdiagram

I need to build a sequence smartdiagram that is more fit with texts inserted to it. Hopefully that looks like the following diagram:
[image]

[image]

I have already tried with the normal smartdiagram (sequence) by default, but I did not know how to do the settings to it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[image]

slightly modified answer of [Ignasi](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1952/ignasi): nodes are in chain, used is `enumitem` for lists in nodes ...

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains, positioning, shapes.symbols}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tikzpicture}{%
    \setlist[itemize]{topsep=0pt, parsep=0pt,
                      leftmargin=2em}
                                }

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 2mm,
  start chain = going right,
 start/.style = {signal, draw=#1, fill=#1!30,
                 text width=32mm, minimum height=28mm, font=\scriptsize,
                 signal pointer angle=150, on chain},
  cont/.style = {start=#1, signal from=west}
                 ]

\node[start=orange] {\bfseries
                     Experimentation\\ Definition \& Supports\\
                     \normalfont
                        \begin{itemize}
                    \item Experimentation suite \& benchmar methodology
                    \item testbeds detailed analysis
                        \end{itemize}   };
\node[cont=olive] {\bfseries
                     Experimentation\\ Definition \& Supports\\
                     \normalfont
                        \begin{itemize}
                    \item Experimentation suite \& benchmar methodology
                    \item testbeds detailed analysis
                        \end{itemize}   };
\node[cont=gray] {\bfseries
                     Experiments execution\\ Analysis \& Benchmark\\[1ex]
                     \hfil
                     \includegraphics[width=22mm]{example-image-a}  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This answer it is very good.

Answer (score 8):

If you don't mind using pure `TikZ`, you can start from:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, shapes.symbols}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    block/.style={signal, text width=3cm, font=\tiny, draw=#1, fill=#1!30, signal pointer angle=140}]

    \node[block=orange] (a) {\textbf{Experimentation}\\\textbf{Definition \& Supports}\\
    \begin{itemize}\item Experimentation suite \& benchmar methodology \item testbeds detailed analysis\end{itemize}};
    \node[block=green, right=2mm of a, signal from=west] (b) {\textbf{Experimentation}\\\textbf{Definition \& Supports}\\
    \begin{itemize}\item Experimentation suite \& benchmar methodology \item testbeds detailed analysis\end{itemize}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: With the help of 'overpic' package, I could also insert the image in the smartdiagram sequence figure, but I still do not know how to adjust the whole figure and make all the parts have the same size. I attached the final figure in the main question panel.

Comment: @AliMansour Ignasi was very kind answering a _just-do-it-for-me_ question. But if you have other request it is better if you add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). You asked many questions, but only very few with a MWE.