# Top-Align Text in TikZ Node

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, text-manipulation

I want the heading ("Meldebogen", "Anklage", "Beweisaufnahme", "Urteil") all on the same vertical height regardless of the content. I figured that simply top-aligning the text in every node would do the trick for me, but googling and texexchanging how to do that didn't yield any results.

[image]

I have tried `\phantom{a}` trickery, `\vspace` and `\vspace*` to no avail.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{svg}
%\usepackage{gensymb}
%\usepackage{siunitx}

%\sisetup {
    %locale = DE,
    %per-mode = symbol
%}

% THEME AND COLOR SETUP
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usecolortheme[RGB={205,0,0}]{structure}
\setbeamertemplate{items}[default]
\setbeamertemplate{sections/subsections in toc}[square]

\newcommand{\quoted}[1]{
    \glqq#1\grqq
}
\date{27. June 2018}

\mode<presentation>{}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains, positioning, shapes.symbols}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\tikzset{start/.style = {signal, draw=#1, fill=#1!30,
             text width=23mm, text=black, minimum height=23mm, font=\tiny,
             signal pointer angle=150, on chain},
         cont/.style = {start=#1, signal from=west, text=black}
        }


\begin{document}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\title{MS Powerpoint and TeX}
\author{Narusan}

\begin{frame}[t, fragile]
\frametitle{Hello World
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        node distance = 2mm,
         start chain = going right,
             ]

        \node[start=darkred!80!black] {\bfseries
                 Meldebogen\\
                 \normalfont
                 \begin{itemize}
                     \item \color{black}{einziger Anhaltspunkt f\"{u}r Verfahren}
                     \item \"{U}berpr\"{u}fung der Angaben schwer                       
                    \end{itemize}   
                };
        \node[cont=gray!60!white] {\bfseries
                 Anklage\\
                 \normalfont
                    \begin{itemize}
                        \item \color{black}{Einflussreiche Nazis konnten Anklage entgehen}
                    \end{itemize} 
             };
        \node[cont=gray!60!white] {\bfseries
            Beweisaufnahme\\
            \normalfont
                    \begin{itemize}
                        \item \color{black}{Kl\"{a}ger ermittelt kaum}
                        \item Persilscheine
                        \item Zeitdruck
                    \end{itemize}   
                };
        \node[cont=gray!60!white] {\bfseries
                 Urteil\\
                  \normalfont
                };
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The whole TikZ script is just a variation of [this code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/411870/124100)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an alternative, it's possible to define the paragraph title can be included  as a `label` instead of being part of the contents. This way they are always located at similar distance from the north border.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{svg}
%\usepackage{gensymb}
%\usepackage{siunitx}

%\sisetup {
    %locale = DE,
    %per-mode = symbol
%}

% THEME AND COLOR SETUP
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usecolortheme[RGB={205,0,0}]{structure}
\setbeamertemplate{items}[default]
\setbeamertemplate{sections/subsections in toc}[square]

\newcommand{\quoted}[1]{
    \glqq#1\grqq
}
\date{27. June 2018}

\mode<presentation>{}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains, positioning, shapes.symbols}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\tikzset{start/.style = {signal, draw=#1, fill=#1!30,
             text width=23mm, text=black, minimum height=23mm, font=\tiny,
             signal pointer angle=150, on chain},
         cont/.style = {start=#1, signal from=west, text=black}
        }


\begin{document}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\title{MS Powerpoint and TeX}
\author{Narusan}

\begin{frame}[t, fragile]
\frametitle{Hello World
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        node distance = 2mm,
         start chain = going right,
         mylabel/.style={anchor=north west,font=\bfseries\tiny, color=black}
             ]

        \node[start=darkred!80!black, label={[mylabel]north west:Meldebogen}] {
                 \begin{itemize}
                     \item \color{black}{einziger Anhaltspunkt f\"{u}r Verfahren}
                     \item \"{U}berpr\"{u}fung der Angaben schwer                       
                    \end{itemize}   
                };
        \node[cont=gray!60!white, label={[mylabel]north west:Anklage}] {    \begin{itemize}
                        \item \color{black}{Einflussreiche Nazis konnten Anklage entgehen}
                    \end{itemize} 
             };
        \node[cont=gray!60!white, label={[mylabel]north west:Beweisaufnahme}] {
                    \begin{itemize}
                        \item \color{black}{Kl\"{a}ger ermittelt kaum}
                        \item Persilscheine
                        \item Zeitdruck
                    \end{itemize}   
                };
        \node[cont=gray!60!white, label={[mylabel]north west:Urteil}] {};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your version works with `\centered` or other alignment stuff, the [bodge](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/438399/124100) doesn't. This is why I accepted this answer.

Answer (score 7):

If you set a (rather large) `text depth` and a `text height` they will align:

```
\tikzset{start/.style = {signal, draw=#1, fill=#1!30,
             text width=23mm, text=black, minimum height=23mm, font=\tiny,text depth=20mm,text height=5mm,
             signal pointer angle=150, on chain},
         cont/.style = {start=#1, signal from=west, text=black}
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Just so that I learn from it: Why is this the case? Pure tex magic? Or is it a workaround like \phantom{}?